# Firebase Javascript: Paginating Posts in Descending Order

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, pagination

My Firebase database stores a list of posts that I want to display to users. I have a pagination, where each page stores 10 posts. However, in it's current form, the database paginates posts from the earliest post to the latest post, rather than showing the newest posts here. This is particularly problematic since Firebase doesn't allow multiple simultaneous queries, and I need to query the key as part of the pagination system, since I need to store the last key of a page each time the user goes to the next page, as all the posts on the new page will start from the last key of the previous page. How do I make sure that the posts are listed in descending (newest to earliest) order?

**Firebase / Javascript**

```
var database = firebase.database().ref();
var postsRef = database.child("posts");


var currentPage = 0;
var keyArray = [];
var limit = 0;

function listThoughts(page) {
    if (page == 0) {
        postsRef.orderByChild("key").limitToFirst(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

            var thought = snapshot.val();

            $("#feed").append("<div class='thought2'><div class='heading'>Posted on " + thought.utctime + " by " + thought.username
            + " | <a href='#' class='reply'>Reply</a></div><div class='else'>" + thought.title + "</div></div");    

            keyArray[0] = thought.key;
        });
    }
    else {
        var elementCount = 0;

        console.log("Staring At: " + keyArray[page - 1]);

        postsRef.orderByChild("key").limitToFirst(10).startAt(keyArray[page - 1]).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            var thought = snapshot.val();
            console.log("THOUGHT: " + thought);
            $("#feed").append("<div class='thought2'><div class='heading'>Posted on " + thought.utctime + " by " + thought.username
            + " | <a href='#' class='reply'>Reply</a></div><div class='else'>" + thought.title + "</div></div");    

            keyArray[page] = thought.key;

            elementCount += 1;
        });

        if (elementCount < 10) {
            limit = page;
        }
    }
}

listThoughts(currentPage);

function changeTab(direction) {
    if (direction == -1 && currentPage > 0) {
        currentPage -= 1;
        console.log("Current Tab: " + currentPage);
        $("#feed").empty();
        listThoughts(currentPage);
    }
    if (direction == 1) {
        if (limit == 0 || currentPage < limit) {
            currentPage += 1;
            console.log("Current Tab: " + currentPage);
            $("#feed").empty();
            listThoughts(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-three">
    <div id="feed">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <button onclick="changeTab(-1)">&lt;</button>
    <button onclick="changeTab(1)">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

This is how my data is structured:
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ7Qv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to store the date as the key for each of the posts. That way, I can both simultaneously query all of the posts in the order from newest to oldest, while being able to track the starting post of the page.